# Why must transuranic elements not be used where life is present?

Tags: sapphire-and-steel

The opening narration to *Sapphire and Steel* implies some lore about transuranic elements (or at least the beings that represent them):

> "All irregularities will be handled by the forces controlling each dimension. **Transuranic heavy elements may not be used where there is life.** Medium atomic weights are available: Gold, Lead, Copper, Jet, Diamond, Radium, Sapphire, Silver and Steel. Sapphire and Steel have been assigned."

Emphasis mine.

It seems to imply that transuranic elements in this context are anathema to life, but is this expanded on in the series at all?

Comment: Given that many of the substances listed, including sapphire and steel, are not elements you might be looking for too deep a meaning here.

Comment: @Michael I'm asking if it's ever explained in-universe. How is that too deep?

Comment: If they don't know what an element is, having a detailed explanation of their properties seems optimistic. Happy to be proven wrong!

Comment: Radioactivity seems a likely reason...

Comment: @Michael  it doesn't actually claim sapphire and steel are elements, just that they are composed of medium atomic weights, which is more or less OK.

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon  but radium is ok? I doubt there was any great thought put into it, although can't prove a negative.

Comment: @Michael As you say; authors of other than hard SF aren't known for the scientific effort put into their stories.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Radium isn't fissionable, but used to be quite fasionable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steel is asked this question in episode 4 of Adventure 1:

> **Steel**: A hundred and fifteen.There are a hundred and fifteen of us. You must never rely on the transuranics.
>
> **Sapphire**: Why not?
>
> **Steel**: They're unstable.

Comment: That is some exposition speak if I have ever seen it. Why would *Sapphire* not know that the transuranic "elements" were unstable?

Answer (score 3):

Unless there's an obscure comic or something I don't believe there is ever any explanation given.

Transuranic elements (i.e. everything after Uranium in the periodic table) are all radioactive, increasingly unstable, and in the late 70s - early 80s were synonymous with imminent nuclear destruction from the Cold War. I think it's safe to assume that's why if e.g. Plutonium turned up to help then the collateral damage would be unacceptable.

Comment: There is an obscure comic, as well as an audio series.